# Merging multiple click functions with load events?

Tags: jquery, ajax, onclick, click

I'm probably being an idiot, however, would it be possible to merge the following:

```
$(function () {
    $("#but1").click(function(){
        $("#RightPanel").load("page1.html");
    });
    $("#but2").click(function(){
        $("#RightPanel").load("page2.html");
    });    
});
```

I was thinking an if/else statement, but can't figure out how to structure it with the load events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw a custom `data-*` attribute on the buttons, and use a common class:

```
<button class="loader" data-page="page1.html">Button 1</button>
<button class="loader" data-page="page2.html">Button 2</button>
```

And the JS:

```
$(".loader").click(function() {
    var page = $(this).data("page");
    $("#RightPanel").load(page);
});
```

If you need to use an `if else` - you can do something like:

```
$("#but1, #but2").click(function(){
    if (this.id == "but1") {
        $("#RightPanel").load("page1.html");
    } else if (this.id == "but2") {
        $("#RightPanel").load("page2.html");
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't really want the page addresses to be visible in the code ideally though. I don't mind the javascript being a little longer than your great solution provides, I just need to make it neater than having a separate function for each button if possible.

Comment: If your pages are in the JavaScript - they're visible in the code. @BN83

Comment: I was under the impression I could scramble the script.js file? @tymeJV

Comment: The edit is perfect thanks. I will accept it in a few minutes when it allows me.

Comment: @BN83 -- You can always minify the JavaScript - I guess my point was that if someone *really* wants to see what page they're going to, they can. Consider anything on the client readable by anyone at anytime.

Comment: I know if someone really wants to find it, they will. Just wanted to obscure it a little.